# Do I need to provide an accessible label for a link whose meaning cannot be derived from its content?

Tags: seo, accessibility, anchor-text, wcag

For example, let's say I have a link whose text, by itself, doesn't do a great job of explaining its meaning:

```html
<div>To complete your transaction, please click <a href="#">here<a>.</div>
```

Say a user using is using an assistive voiceover interface and the `Tab` button to navigate the page.

For discussion, let's ignore a suggested solution, [putting meaningful text inside the anchor element itself](https://web.dev/labels-and-text-alternatives/#label-buttons-and-links).

What is the next best solution? Adding an `aria-label` with meaningful text? For example:

```html
<div>To complete your transaction, please click <a aria-label="To complete your transaction, please click here">here<a></div>
```

Will this be redundant for the user? Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you even need an `<a>` tag. If the link doesn't navigate to another page then you should be using a `<button>` tag.

Yes, you can use the **aria-label** as you have described and you can also use the normal `<a href="#" **title=""**>` title tag instead, as all screen readers use that in the absence of an aria-label tag.

However, in your example, there is a more robust and accepted way to do it because the label text you are trying to emphasise is already on the page so you should use the attribute **aria-labelledby=""** instead.

This is the correct solution for your exact example scenario (because the relevant text is already on the page).

```
<div id="your-id">To complete your transaction, please click <a aria-labelledby="your-id">here<a></div>
```

You should only use aria-label="" if the text you're after can't be found on the page.

You can still use aria-labelledby="" even if that text is somewhere else on the page. For example, you could just wrap that text in a span tag like so:

```
<span id="your-id">To complete your transaction...</span>
```